# how to stop a while true loop from another function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyqt5

how can I stop a while true function from another function in python, so when I click a button in the graphical interface it runs a function to stop a while true loop in another function?
this is the code:

```
def com():
    self.cancel_btn.setEnabled(True)
    do = multiprocessing.Process(target=background.go).start()
        
def stop():
    pass
```

and this is all main function (the one with while true is with them):

```
def go(sure = False):
    while True:
        if sure:
           break
        print("test")

def rest():
    go(sure = True)
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to use a global variable to control the while loop. For example, `while VAR`, and update this `VAR` in the other function

Comment: If this were true multiprocessing code where the code doing the stopping and the code needing to be stopped were in different threads, you might need to do something a bit more complicated.  You would use a multiprocessing.Event in which `stop()` calls `event.set()` and the loop checks for `event.is_set()`.

Comment: if you use multiprocessing then you have to use `event` or `queue` to send information to other process and `while True` would have to check this `event` or `queue` in every loop. `if queue.get() == 'stop': break`

Comment: Please note that: 1. Multiprocessing doesn't allow sharing of memory; 2. Generally speaking, 99% of the times threading is enough (and much simpler); 3. Proper implementation should use classes and instance attributes, especially when dealing with UI elements that normally require a more OOP to be followed, so individual functions and global variables should  *not* be used. That said, the concept remains: if you have a loop and you want to stopi it, you need some sort of "switch" that can break it as soon as it's set, there's no other option. How that switch is checked and set, is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that once the function is called, the parameter is given (True) and will do it forever. The only solution is to make a global variable. This will make sure to update the variable everywhere in the pipeline.
Right now, you're passing to the function `true` and even if you change it, the function will use the value that was passed.

For `global` usage, check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) :

Comment: Thank you guys For your help I fixed the problem hope you have a nice day